# python pandas installation issues

Tags: python, pandas, homebrew, easy-install

I have tried installing from

1. source (`python setup.py install` into the extracted tar ball dir)
2. using `pip`
3. using `easy_install` but nothing seems to work...I have downloaded and upgraded xcode, installed command-line tools..

I cloned the github repository for pandas

```
cd ../pandas
python setup.py install 
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to pandas.egg-info/requires.txt
writing pandas.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pandas.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pandas.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pandas.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'setupegg.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
writing manifest file 'pandas.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying pandas/version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/pandas
running build_ext
**gcc-4.2 not found, using clang instead**
building 'pandas.index' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c pandas/index.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/pandas/index.o
In file included from pandas/index.c:260:
In file included from pandas/src/klib/khash_python.h:3:
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:573:1: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
KHASH_MAP_INIT_STR(str, size_t)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pandas/src/klib/khash.h:565:2: note: expanded from macro 'KHASH_MAP_INIT_STR'
    KHASH_INIT(name, kh_cstr_t, khval_t, 1, kh_str_hash_func, kh_str_hash_equal)
    ^
```

---more output like that...and in the end

```
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-      packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_c934e02-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for pandas==0.10.1.dev-c934e02
Searching for pytz
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pytz/
Reading http://pytz.sourceforge.net
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=79122
Reading http://www.stuartbishop.net/Software/pytz
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/pytz/
Best match: pytz 2012h
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/p/pytz/pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg#md5=4258fcfc023e9ff0057405d935fc6e1d
Processing pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg
creating /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg
Extracting pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg to /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding pytz 2012h to easy-install.pth file

Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2012h-py2.7.egg
-----
Installed /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.2.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for numpy==1.6.2
Best match: numpy 1.6.2
Adding numpy 1.6.2 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for pandas==0.10.1.dev-c934e02

ipython

Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.14.dev -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import pandas
```

seems to work without issues..

when i use easy_install to install pandas, the on-screen output seems to suggest that it worked but on loading, python is not able to find the library

```
sudo easy_install pandas
Searching for pandas
Best match: pandas 0.10.1.dev-c934e02
Processing pandas-0.10.1.dev_c934e02-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
pandas 0.10.1.dev-c934e02 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.1.dev_c934e02-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for pandas
Finished processing dependencies for pandas

dekumar-mn:ipython dekumar$ python
Python 2.7.3 (v2.7.3:70274d53c1dd, Apr  9 2012, 20:52:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: print `sys.path` inside python to ensure that Pandas' path is included

Comment: You have a second Python 2.7 in `/usr/local`. Where did you get it from? Why did you install it? Do you actually need it?

Comment: i may have deleted the mac os x default version of python 2.7..and therefore had to do a fresh install using brew install python --universal

Comment: Mixing package managers is rarely a good idea

Comment: @sgtpepper: No, you did not delete the default version, because you clearly have two different Python 2.7 versions. Unless… do you have _two_ extra Python installations, somehow? At any rate, installing more Pythons never makes things simpler. If your system is broken, fix it. Just running the Mountain Lion installer to "upgrade" to the same version you already have will probably take care of anything that's wrong.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I don't think he mixed package managers; he's just got the one, Homebrew. Of course brew doesn't (and can't) control the built-in Apple stuff. (Think of it like FreeBSD, where the OS installer controls `/usr`, and `portage` controls `/usr/local`.)

Comment: @abarnert: I agree that brew can't tinker with built-in stuff, but OP mentions trying to install from source, `pip` and `easy_install`. They might conflict with Homebrew

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: No, Homebrew explicitly says to always use `easy_install`/`pip` (and `gem` and `cpan`), whether you're using its Python or Apple's. Except in a few very special cases, it does not come with recipes for Python/Ruby/Perl modules. See https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Gems%2C-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules for details.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the link. This is news to me :)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Actually, that was the wrong link for the policy. See "Other - non-homebrew - Python bindings" under https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python instead. (But it's worth reading both pages anyway if you plan to use Homebrew.)

Answer (score 7):

You have multiple versions of Python 2.7. You installed `pandas` for one version, and then tried to import it into the other, and you can't do that, because they have separate site libraries.

If you need multiple versions of Python 2.7 for some reason, you have to learn how to manage multiple versions of Python. For example, always be sure whether you're using `/usr/bin/easy_install` or `/usr/local/bin/easy_install`, and use the one that goes with the `python` you plan to run.

But you probably don't need multiple versions. If you just uninstall the non-Apple one, everything will be a lot easier.

You can figure out the details from the paths in your logs. The manual install went to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`, which is where Apple's `/usr/bin/python` looks. But the `easy_install` went to `/usr/local/lib/python/2.7/site-packages`, which is where the third-party (presumably Homebrew, from the `brew` tag?) `/usr/local/bin/python`. So clearly, the first `python` on your path is `/usr/bin/python`, while the first `easy_install` is `/usr/local/bin/easy_install`. That's going to lead to confusion, as it did here.

Even worse, if you install `ipython` into both Pythons, whichever one you install second is going to end up as `/usr/local/bin/ipython`, which is going to lead to even *more* confusion.

If you do `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pandas`, you can use `pandas` in the Apple Python. To make sure that's the one you run, always do `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ipython`. If you do `sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install pandas`, you can use `pandas` in the third-party Python. To make sure that's the one you run, always do `/usr/local/bin/python` or `/usr/local/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ipython`.

Looking at your comments, and your more detailed edit, it's possible that you actually have *two* third-party Pythons here, which makes things even more confusing. If both of them prefer `/usr/local/bin` (and unless you're using MacPorts or Fink, they do), you've probably got one of them half-overwritten by the other, and there's just no way you're going to get this working. If that's the case, I would recommend that you do something radical. If you're not willing to do an install-from-scratch-with-settings-import of OS X, at least `rm -rf /usr/local /Library/Python ~/Library/Python`, then reinstall `brew` and any other third-party stuff you need, and this time make sure to only install one extra Python (although zero would still be better!).

Meanwhile, two minor side notes:

1. It's almost always better to use `pip` than `easy_install`. If you don't have it, `sudo easy_install pip`, and now you do. (The only common exceptions to that "almost" are for `pip` itself, and for `readline`.)
2. Don't use `sudo` with Homebrew. Homebrew goes through a lot of trouble to set up all of the directories it touches so you never need `sudo`. Once you start doing `sudo brew`, `sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install`, etc., you end up breaking that, so later installations get permissions errors, and it takes a lot of work with `brew doctor` to fix everything.

Comment: thanks very much..but it is very likely that I have damaged / overwritten the default mac osx python version..so, i do not have the option of uninstalling the non apple version..will review your comments on how to separate out the stuff in /usr/local/bin vs. the the binaries in other paths more carefully and reply..

Comment: Why do you think it's likely that you've damaged/overwritten the default python? First, it clearly starts up a valid interpreter when you type `python`. And if it were broken, there are parts of the OS that depend on it, so all kinds of things would go wrong. And, for the same reason, if you _have_ damaged it, the right answer is to fix it, not to install another Python and add to the confusion.

Comment: i have downloaded 10.8.2 again on the mac using app store..it shows  as downloaded but it is not giving me the option to "upgrade" to it..where can i find instructions to force this "upgrade"...google search is not very helpful

Comment: @sgtpepper: This is really a question for Apple Support or Apple's forums, or at least superuser.com, not SO. But let's see what I can think of. What did the MAS download give you? If it's not an installer you can double-click and use the Installer menu on, you may have to get the updater from the Support site (I think http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1581 is the right URL?) and run that. Alternatively, Show Contents on whichever installer you have may show a bunch of sub-installer packages, and you can find the one that includes Python by guessing, then checking the "Show Files" menu option…